# Arduino Mega to ADC SPI communication is not working

Tags: arduino, spi, adc

I'm using SPI communication to try to connect my **Arduino Mega 2560** as the master with an ADC chip as the slave (`Max 1247`) in external clock mode, but I keep receiving the same values `(RB1 = 255, RB2 = 255, RB3 = 255)` or all zeros whenever I run my code. There is also a touch screen (which works) connected. Everything works except the [ADC chip](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/analog/data-converters/analog-to-digital-converters/MAX1247.html/tb_tab1) communication with the Arduino.

I have tried deleting the define header, and varying the clock. Neither change anything (which might be because of other errors).

```
//Portion of Header

//Defining SPI connections

#define SELPIN 53 //Selection Pin

#define DATAOUT 50 //MIS0

#define DATAIN  51 //MOSI

#define SPICLOCK  52//Clock

#define SSTRB 43 //SSTRB


#include <Adafruit_GFX.h> 

#include "MCUFRIEND_kbv.h"


MCUFRIEND_kbv tft(A3, A2, A1, A0, A4);

int sstrb = 0;  

byte TB1 = B11101111;  

byte RB1;  

byte RB2;  

byte RB3;  

byte RB4;

//SETUP

void setup(){  

  pinMode(SELPIN, OUTPUT);  

  pinMode(sstrb, INPUT);  

  pinMode(DATAOUT, INPUT); 

  pinMode(DATAIN, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(SPICLOCK, OUTPUT);

  //disable device to start.

  digitalWrite(SELPIN, HIGH);

  digitalWrite(SPICLOCK, LOW);

  digitalWrite(DATAIN, LOW);

}

void loop(){

//Some other touch screen stuff prefaces this..

else if (currentPage == '3') {
    if (tp.z > myTouch.pressureThreshhold) {
      x = tp.x;
      y = tp.y;
      //Back button command

      if ((x >= 20) && (x <= 900) && (y >= 0) && (y <= 320)) {
        homescreen();
        currentPage = '0';
      }

      else if ((x >= 700) && (x <= 800) && (y >= 350) && (y <= 875)) {
        //loop

        SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(1000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));

        digitalWrite(SELPIN, LOW);

        //The line beneath might take care of transmitting dataout, and receiving datain (vs currently doing seperately)?.

        RB1 = SPI.transfer(TB1);

        Serial.print("\r\nRB1="); Serial.print(RB1);

        digitalRead(sstrb);

        if (sstrb == 0){

          RB2 = SPI.transfer(0x0);

          Serial.print("\r\nRB2="); Serial.print(RB2);

          RB3 = SPI.transfer(0x0);

          Serial.print("\r\nRB3="); Serial.print(RB3);

          digitalWrite(SELPIN, HIGH);

          digitalWrite(SELPIN, LOW);

          SPI.endTransaction();

          tft.fillRoundRect(40, 20, 300, 70, 15, RED);

          tft.setCursor(150, 45);

          tft.setTextColor(WHITE);

          tft.setTextSize(3);

          tft.print("3A");

          tp = myTouch.getPoint();

          pinMode(YP, OUTPUT);

          pinMode(XM, OUTPUT);

          digitalWrite(YP, HIGH);

          digitalWrite(XM, HIGH);

        }

        else{

          Serial.print("SSTRB is high");

        }

      }

    }

  }

}
```

Errors include RB1 = 255; RB2 = 255; RB3 = 255 or all zeroes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't definitely say if this is the root of your problem, but I found the following:

You defined SSTRB to be pin 43

```
#define SSTRB 43 //SSTRB
```

but you are actually never using this value. Instead you also defined

```
int sstrb = 0;
```

a few lines below, which you are then using to define pin 0 as input

```
pinMode(sstrb, INPUT);
```

I assume this should rather be

```
pinMode(SSTRB, INPUT);
```

Then, there are these lines in your loop

```
digitalRead(sstrb);
if (sstrb == 0){
```

where digitalRead actually does nothing (reads from pin 0 and discards the value), I assume you wanted to write

```
sstrb = digitalRead(SSTRB);
```

otherwise, `sstrb` never actually changes and is always 0.

Also, since the datasheet (https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1246-MAX1247.pdf#page=13) states that

> In external clock mode, [...]. SSTRB pulses high for one clock
>   period after the last bit of the control byte.

and you are using external clock mode, I assume you rather want to wait for this pulse to finish before you continue. You could do a busy wait like this:

```
bool wasHigh = false;
do {
    sstrb = digitalRead(SSTRB);
    if( sstrb == 1 ){ 
        wasHigh = true; 
    }
}while( !(wasHigh && sstrb == 0) );
```

Please note that if the pulse occurs before this wait or if it never occurs, you will stay in this loop endlessly. You may wan't to add a break condition or timeout here. You could of course also use an interrupt instead to solve this problem.

Additional note: You are calling `endTransaction` in the branch where you check if `sstrb` is 0 only. I don't know how the SPI library handles beginning a transaction again without ending the old one first, it's probably working fine, I just wanted to let you know that this may be a potential pitfall.

Comment: This helped a lot with my confusion on sstrb. I also discovered that I was wrong to group SELPIN and the pin that connects to CS. I thought that they were the same, but once I separated them, and updated my code to match along with adding the section you included on sstrb, everything worked as intended.

Comment: Great to hear that everything works now. Always happy to help.